# Mock Chained DB query in Django unit test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I have a function that allows users to create a new entry in DB. But before that, I had a check if the user's existing records are less than the permissible range. Below is the function implementation

```
def is_allowed_to_create(permissible_range):
    count = MyModel.objects.filter(query)[:permissible_range].count()
    return not count >= permissible_range
```

Inside the test file, I am doing

```
    @mock.patch('MyApp.models.MyModel.objects')
    def test_is_allowed_to_create(self, mock_qs, *args, **kwargs):
        mock_qs.filter.return_value = mock_qs
        mock_qs.count.return_value = 10
        self.assertTrue(is_allowed_to_create(5))
```

And the error I am getting is
`TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int'`.

So what I understood from the error is, my code is not setting the proper return value for the entire DB query ie `MyModel.objects.filter(query)[:permissible_range].count()` . How can I set mock value for `MyModel.objects.filter(query)[:permissible_range].count()` as an integer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made changes in my test function, since I an using `slicing` which internally calls `__getitems__` method, so I need to mock that as well

Here is the updated code

```
    @mock.patch('MyApp.models.MyModel.objects')
    def test_is_allowed_to_create(self, mock_qs, *args, **kwargs):
        mock_qs.filter.return_value = mock_qs
        mock_qs.__getitems__.return_value = mock_qs
        mock_qs.count.return_value = 10
        self.assertTrue(is_allowed_to_create(5))
```